# CheckPoint SecuRemote / SecureClient on Vista 64

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit

According to this page, CheckPoint's SecuRemote client is not supported on Vista 64:

https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk36681

Unfortunately in working with the systems team they will not confirm if the other two clients (SSL Network Extender or Endpoint Connect) are supported by their environment.

Does anyone know if it would be possible to do the following?

1. Install VMware Workstation on my Vista 64 system (host)
2. install a Vista 32-bit OS in a virtual machine (guest)
3. Install SecuRemote VPN client within the guest (Vista 32)
4. Get my Vista 64 machine (host) to use the VPN connection from the guest

Any other ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Usually the guest gets the network connection from the host. I doubt it can work in the other direction. The host has virtual network adapters for the guest to use, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do exactly what you are proposing.  You could also use virtualbox, which is free.  They both work the same

Comment: How would I go about doing #4?

Comment: #4 might not work.